# Вернуть результат со второго Activity startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

Есть Activity1 , которое передает в Activity2 несколько параметров при нажатии соответствующих кнопок, из которых потом формируется тест, например: длина массива и значение таймера.
После окончания теста нужно получить из Activity2 значение оценки при нажатии кнопки назад и записать в текстовое поле Activity1.
В Activity2  все передается, а обратно в Activity1 оценка нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Activity1

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity_test_delenie.class);
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_slozno:
            lengthPrim = 70;
            second = 150000;
            intent.putExtra("sekondDif", second);
            intent.putExtra("lengthPrimDif", lengthPrim);
            startActivityForResult(intent,RequestCode.REQUEST_CODE_REZYLTAT_SL);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonNorma:
            lengthPrim = 50;
            second = 170000;
            intent.putExtra("sekondNorm",second);
            intent.putExtra("lengthPrimNorm",lengthPrim);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode.REQUEST_CODE_REZYLTAT_NORM);
            break;
       ....
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){

            case RequestCode.REQUEST_CODE_REZYLTAT_SL:
                String name = data.getStringExtra("rezylt_ball");
                text_rezylt1.setText("Баллов" + name);
                break;
            case RequestCode.REQUEST_CODE_REZYLTAT_NORM:
                String name1 = data.getStringExtra("rezylt_ball");
                text_rezylt2.setText("Баллов" + name1);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Activity2

```
//метод, который выводит оценку по 10-бальной шкале
public void grade () {
    double grade = 10*bal/lengthPrim;
    double result = Math.round(grade * 100.0) / 100.0;
    resulttxt = Double.toString(result);
    textViewYouGrade.setText("Ваша оценка: ");
    textViewYourGradeNum.setText(resulttxt);
} 

public void onClick_n(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("rezylt_ball",resulttxt);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(requestCode == RESULT_OK){
```

не `requestCode`, а `resultCode`